# Did David cause the Covenant to stop near to his location?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

The whole plot of [Covenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien:_Covenant) seems to hinge on a *"singular, random"* event, as described by android Walter: a random burst of neutrinos that could not be detected by the ship, that causes the Weyland colonizer ship to stop just nearby the planet where the Weyland's android happens to be cultivating xenomorphs, and waiting for a ride.

I really like this film but I just don't buy it that this was a single random event.

**Is it merely coincidence that the mothership with 2000 colonists just happen to pit stop right next to the highly xenomorph-infected planet?**

Comment: You don't need to "buy" it. It happened and that's the plot.

Comment: There were some unconnected sub-questions here that I've edited out.

Comment: So, the plot just relies on a random event, that what you think?

Comment: Sure, why not. We wouldn't have watched the film if the colony shop had just sailed on by.

Comment: But you truly believe that the whole ship is just going to stop half-way thorugh because of some "neutrino burst" that the Walter android wouldn't want to go throught the whole "core code review" and then just happen to find android David a few miles from where the ship stopped? You're saying the plot is just flawed.

Comment: Or perhaps the plot is just randomly-based, which is very difficult to me to believe.

Comment: I think a better question might be: "Is there any (cannon?) evidence (from films or books?) that the neutrino blast was anything other than a random event?”.

Comment: In real life, all sort of wild, incredible coincidences happen. In stories we consume, coincidence as an explanation for an event is very frowned upon. Authors from times past would usually put something like hand of God, hand of Fate, providence or similar as an explanation for those acts of random chance which start or resolve a story. Modern authors frown at using it at all, because modern audiences don't tolerate coincidence at all. Make of this what you will.

Comment: @Pam - Purely for the record, a *canon* is a body of works from a single source whereas a *cannon* is a big metal shooty thing that goes ***"boom!"***.

Comment: If you find the random inciting event unsatisfying, here’s some protective head-cannon: Weyland-Yutani was aware of the neutrino risk, and somehow manipulated that ship’s course to pass through the dangerous area intentionally, in the hope that it would result in the eventual retrieval of life-forms like those encountered in _Prometheus_.

Comment: @Valorum, thanks for the edit, the question is far better now :)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, in fact, reading all these posts, I now believe it was intentional, but in a simpler way: Shaw and David left LV-223 and they were messaging Earth. All the time David is in contact with Weyland Corp., which is just happens to have a thing for breeding xenomorphs. David tells Weyland they have a real cool bio-weapon and they are heading for the Engineer's planet. Weyland knows David will breed the thing, and sends him 2000 mothers, which then they calculate will crash just neraby.

Comment: @Arc - I really don't think there's any justification for that in the film, but it's a cool fanfic.

Comment: @Valorum, nice, "fanfic" is in my vocabulary now :)

Comment: Thanks @Valorum. That's funny. I did pause when I put cannon, but I was totally confused by the musical canon and opted for "not Pachelbel", not thinking about boom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All signs point to the phenomenon being natural. David certainly doesn't have the wherewithal to cause a "stellar ignition" from his place on the surface of the nearby planet, nor could he have predicted that this particular ship was passing nearby and that they had just stopped to unfurl their energy collectors at that precise moment.

> **TENNESSEE:** *What the hell was it?*
>
> **WALTER:** *A highly charged shockwave from a
> nearby stellar ignition. As the
> sails were deployed for the refuel,
> we absorbed the full brunt of the
> storm. If we had--*
>
> <sub><sup>[Covenant: Screenplay](https://www.avpgalaxy.net/files/scripts/alien-covenant-2015-11-20.pdf)</sup></sub>

In the [official novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Alien:_Covenant_(novel)), it's described as a *'cloud'* of charged particles, one that just happened to be masked by a wide variety of other [spacey-wacey stuff](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NegativeSpaceWedgie) that's in the vicinity.

> “Sector 106. Very close. Source was masked, hence the unusual—no, extreme proximity prior to discovery. Undetectable earlier due to **unique concatenation of spatial and gravitational distortion in the vicinity.** Apologies. Initial analysis was insufficient to gauge intensity, as well as proximity. Reappraisal suggests possibility the event could be substantial. Unable at this time to predict risk.”

The system and its surrounds are clogged with crap that's accumulated nearby. Again, there's no sign that this is intentional on anyone's part.

> Oram was gratified to be able to interject. **“View obviously is blocked
> from Earth. Dense nebulae, dust cloud, periodic flares screening out
> the infrared**—maybe when the searcher for this sector made its pass,
> this world was at perihelion, on the opposite side of its star from
> Earth.

Comment: Oh, thanks @Valorum for the official novelisation, very cool indeed. I just found out some clues that it was a deliberate crash: **"source was masked"**. As I explain in my other comment, there could be an arrangement between David and Weyland Corp. (as they were communicating with each other until Shaw and David crashed in the Engineer's planet) so as to make the colonist ship wreck just nearby. Remember Weyland Corp. is just fanatic for breeding xenomorphs.

Comment: But your answer has some cool information on it, so I upvoted.

Comment: @Arc - I think you've misunderstood. The source was masked by natural phenomena, not masked *deliberately*.

Comment: Well I might have been a bit too conspiracist on this one, but I guess Weyland conspiring to evolve xenomorphs is way cooler than David being helped by "chance". I guess we will have to wait some years more to know exactly, now that Disney bought 21th Century, and Ridley's plans were put on hold...

Comment: +∞ For "spacey-wacey stuff".

Comment: Well, I've watched some of Ridley's interviews, and while there's no direct clue for my fanfic, I don't really think he's into something too deep on that, so I agree with your answer.